# How to Run a Program and Get its Output

Tags: c#, process, output

In C#, I want to run a program and wait for the user to exit in order to get what was saved. For example, I want to run Photoshop or MSpaint, wait for the user to finish editing and, after saving, to get the file (jpg, png, etc) or at least the path of the file.

I have been unable to determine how to go about this.

Comment: Just to clarify - by get its output do you mean console output or user interface output? Or a file that was saved from that program?

Comment: And "All my efforts were useless" translates to what more specifically?

Comment: You can get the output of a _console_ process. But a program with a user interface such as Photoshop or Paint does not have an _output_ in that sense. Yes, it may manipulate and save images, but that's application specific and beyond your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably going to depend heavily on the program you wish to use. If you use a program with an API to make calls and get feedback, then maybe you can do this. For Photoshop and MSPaint, I'm a bit skeptical they'd have this feature. In the end, what you might wish to do, is keep some kind of input box open and await the user to paste the path themselves. Either that or find such a program with the API you're looking for or make your very own image editor.